# Ender 3 v3 SE - ABS slowly accumulates on nozzle

Tags: troubleshooting, nozzle

I picked up a cheap Ender 3 v3 SE printer a few months ago. While it works fine for PLA filament, I've been having an issue when printing ABS. My prints come out fine, but plastic will accumulate slowly on the nozzle. It starts at the tip and works its way up - it's not leaking from the threads. Eventually, it builds up enough that it deposits itself on the print. Sometimes, the head crashes into this blob and causes a layer shift.

What I've been doing is cleaning the nozzle between prints. If I don't, it almost definitely will fall off and cause problems. On longer (more than 1-2 hour) prints, I have to pause the print and clean it multiple times.

I've printed anywhere from 220-235 °C but it makes no difference. I don't think it's a clog because it's done this from day 1 on ABS, but has had no issues with PLA, and I've switched between them multiple times. What should I troubleshoot next?

Comment: Have you measured the ABS filament with a caliper and copared this to the PLA filament diameter? Have you calibrated the flow for ABS? A filament diameter difference could cause the ABS to overextrude, in that case you should use the flow modifier to adjust. If you don't have calipers, print test cubes at 0.98, 0.96, 0.94, etc. until it doesn't catch on the nozzle.